# Como colocar legenda em graficos de distribuições no ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho o seguinte gráfico da distribuição exponencial, quero colocar uma legenda mostrando qual o parametro da minha exponencial.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,5)),aes(x))+
  stat_function(fun=dexp,colour='red',size=1.4)+
  stat_function(fun=dexp,args=list(rate=.5),colour='deepskyblue1',size=1.4)+
  stat_function(fun=dexp,args=list(rate=.75),colour='goldenrod2',size=1.4)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Você tem que colocar as cores como uma estética (dentro do `aes`). E se você quiser utilizar essas cores específicas ('red', 'deepskyblue1', 'goldenrod2'), elas têm que ser passadas como parâmetros no `scale_color_manual`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,5)),aes(x))+ 
  stat_function(fun=dexp, aes(colour='1'),size=1.4)+ 
  stat_function(fun=dexp,args=list(rate=.5), aes(colour='0.5'),size=1.4)+ 
  stat_function(fun=dexp,args=list(rate=.75), aes(colour='0.75'),size=1.4) +
  scale_color_manual("Rate",values = c('red', 'deepskyblue1', 'goldenrod2'))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]