# Como faço para fazer aparecer a legenda de cada curva na área de impressão do gráfico?

Tags: r

```r
grafico <- read.csv("Pasta1.csv", header = F, sep = ";")

library(ggplot2)

Experimental <- ggplot(grafico)+
  geom_line(size=1.2, aes(x=V1, y=V2))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Experimental" = "green", "nulo" = "null"))

angulo30 <- Experimental+
  geom_line(size=1, col="blue", aes(x=V3, y=V4))

angulo36 <- plot30+
  geom_line(size=1, col="red", aes(x=V5, y=V6))

angulo42 <- plot36+
  geom_line(size=1, col="green", aes(x=V7, y=V8)) +
  labs(x="Displacement (mm)", y="Load (kN)")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 12)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 12))
```

angulo42

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Olá Paulo. Você precisa colocar `color` dentro de `aes`. Veja estas postagens: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41503/como-colocar-legenda-em-graficos-de-distribui%c3%a7%c3%b5es-no-ggplot e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363454/legenda-no-ggplot-n%c3%a3o-aparece

Comment: Obrigado, @CarlosEduardoLagosta! Consegui!

Comment: Fico feliz. Se foram as outras postagens que te ajudaram a resolver, recomendo excluir sua pergunta, para não haver duplicação dentro do SO.